# problem using std::map. Are there known obstructing macros?

Tags: c++

I have a header file, where I try to collect global variable declarations. When trying to typedef a map I get the following error:

```
n file included from Dis0_10.ino:7:
/var/folders/jl/nv1qvh6n569cxq9xxfd6dx980000gn/T/build8295701509021940161.tmp/globals.h:23: error: expected initializer before '<' token
```

relevant code snippets from global.h are:

```
#ifndef GLOBALS
#define GLOBALS
#include <map>
```

...

```
typedef std::map<uint8_t,uint8_t> memmap_t;
```

I have no clue, why this statement should fail. I consider it rather straight forward. So I think there must be some problems of [this kind here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558697/c-map-expected-initializer-before-token). Or am I missing another include?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ standard library is not available for arduino.

Some implementations of similar containers or certain functions exist on the web, but for the most part the standard library is impractical on a device with such small amounts of both RAM and program memory.

An implementation of SGI STL for AVR has been documented here: http://andybrown.me.uk/wk/2011/01/15/the-standard-template-library-stl-for-avr-with-c-streams/

map is mentioned as being particularly impractical for anything less than an arduino mega(1280). An example of maps working is included on the page so it seems like a good lead if you really must use one, but I've never done this myself so I cant guarantee it still works.

Comment: In general, any sort of dynamic memory allocation is usually considered poor practices in embedded code development.

Comment: Ok this is definitely decision making information. I thought of map as a way of saving memory and cpu time. If the memory overhead is rather, I can go back to a sparse array and put into program memory. Thanks for the clue.